# Проблемы с кодировкой MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "blog";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$showRecordPerPage = 15;
if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])){
$currentPage = $_GET['page'];
}else{
$currentPage = 1;
}
$startFrom = ($currentPage * $showRecordPerPage) - $showRecordPerPage;
$totalEmpSQL = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts";
$allEmpResult = mysqli_query($conn, $totalEmpSQL);
$totalEmployee = mysqli_num_rows($allEmpResult);
$lastPage = ceil($totalEmployee/$showRecordPerPage);
$firstPage = 1;
$nextPage = $currentPage + 1;
$previousPage = $currentPage - 1;
$empSQL = "SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate, postCategory, postImg
FROM `blog_posts` LIMIT $startFrom, $showRecordPerPage";
$empResult = mysqli_query($conn, $empSQL);
?>
```

Написал такой код для пангинации, но он почему выводит кракозябры вместо текста.
    Как это исправить?

Comment: $conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: Использовать поиск по сайту, набрать там "Проблемы с кодировкой MySQL
 php" прочитать сотню вариаций одной и той же проблемы и решения этой проблемы